# Twitter Search for All Words Ending with... (Corpus Linguistics)

Tags: twitter, corpus, linguistics

I am using Twitter to a create a corpus and I need to search for Tweets containing specific grammatical constructions with, e.g., verbs ending in `-ing`.

For example: I would like to search for Tweets containing the construction:

`I enjoy` + `any verb ending in -ing`

Results should include all Tweets with any instance of `I enjoy` + `verb ending in -ing`, such as "I enjoy swimming," "I enjoy listening to music," etc.

I understand the Twitter API does not support regular expressions, so any ideas are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can try.

The first is creating a list of verbs you want to search for, and then searching for an exact phrase *and* a list of potential verbs:

`"I enjoy" doing OR eating OR seeing`

https://twitter.com/search?l=&q=%22I%20enjoy%22%20doing%20OR%20eating%20OR%20seeing&src=typd

The second is to *just* search for `"I enjoy"` and then filtering the results client side.  I'd suggest using the streaming API for this if you want to get the most results.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, Terence. But once I got my results using the second method, how could I filter them so as to find all instances of "I enjoy" + "VERBing" for all possible VERBS?

Comment: You'll need a list of every verb in the English language. For filtering, ask a new question and indicate what programming language you're using.

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've found a workaround by P.O.S. tagging (NLTK for Python 3) all the results from the second method you suggested. That allows me to simply search for e.g. "I enjoy" + GERUND.

Comment: Cool. If this answer has helped, please click the Tick button.